# Sampling With Replacement No-Repeats

Tags: probability, statistics

I am about to do a survey on a population of 250 individuals.
I will be performing a **Two Sample T Test For A Difference Between Two Populations** but am having trouble meeting the conditions for the **10% Rule**.
I hope to have a sample size of >30 but the 10% Rule limits me to only 25 or less individuals.

Since the **10% Rule** is applied for **sampling without replacement**, if I performed **sampling with replacement**, would that solve the problem? I have written a program that generates random numbers (for example 1-100) capable of numbers repeating. **However, for the sampling procedure of selecting individuals, I cannot have repeats so I did a bit of changes to the program.** The program will generate 20 numbers with possible repeats, and whenever there is a repeat in the 20 numbers, the program **re-generates until there are no repeats**.

*This way, I can have a set of numbers that are individual of one another but with no repeats. Is this allowed in statistics?*

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a questionnaire that is required to fill by the those poor 250 folks?

Comment: No, the population is 250 individuals. We need a sample of greater than 25 since 25 is too less, and that is the problem we are trying to solve. Yes, the sample (greater than 25) will have to do a questionnaire.

Comment: Since sample size is less than 30 just apply T-test to test the significance.Your way of limiting random number generator method to not allow repeat will not do good.Since random numbers have tendency to repeat and distinct and there is specified entropy for the random numbers.By not allowing repeat you would distort entropy and random number generation procedure will not be trustworthy.

Comment: But to use Central Limit Theorem, you cannot assume Normal for sample sizes less than 30.

Comment: who told normal I told u about t-test and if I remembered correctly T-distribution is slightly NOT normal.

Comment: So to wait until there is a sequence with no repeats is not good? But the probability of getting a sequence of no repeats from all the possible sequences (with possible repeats) is really small though. If use my method, does it violate any rule or is it just not a good practice? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the population of 250 coming from?  Are they chosen from yet a larger population?  Is so then the 10% should apply to the larger population so you should be ok.